# Windows Search Indexer eating 5GB RAM (86% of total)

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-search

Sometimes Search Indexer is eating RAM like crazy, especially if I have JetBrains IDEs opened (PHPStorm, IntelliJ) but even when none of these are active and I'm only browsing the web this Indexer is still the nr 1 most memory consuming service on my system.

I didn't notice this behavior on my other PC with same version of Windows.

I'd rather not disable it completely because I want to be able to search apps on Win key, but how can I at least decrease its memory usage?

I might not have access to all Windows features as it's a company laptop controlled via Active Directory - could it be the reason their bloatware is causing Indexer to work its tail off 24/7?

[image]